# How to scrape a webpage that uses javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using requests and BeautifulSoup to scrape data from a real estate website. It has several numbered "pages" that show dozens of apartaments. I wrote a loop that run across all these pages and collect data from the apartments, but unfortunately they use javascript, and, because of that, the code only returns the apartments of the first page. I also tried something with selenium, but ran across the same problem.

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions!

Here's the code:

````
# Create empty lists to append data scraped from URL
# Number of lists depends on the number of features you want to extract

lista_preco = []
lista_endereco = []
lista_tamanho = []
lista_quartos = []
lista_banheiros = []
lista_vagas = []
lista_condominio = []
lista_amenidades = []
lista_fotos = []
lista_sites = []

n_pages = 0

for page in range(1, 15):
    n_pages += 1
    url = "https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/bahia/salvador/apartamento_residencial/"+'?pagina='+str(page)
    url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
    house_containers = soup.find_all('div', {'class' :'js-card-selector'})
    if house_containers != []:
        for container in house_containers:
            
            # Price
            price = container.find_all('section', class_='property-card__values')[0].text
            try:
                price = int(price[:price.find('C')].replace('R$', '').replace('.','').strip())
            except:
                price = 0
            lista_preco.append(price)

            # Zone
            location = container.find_all('span', class_='property-card__address')[0].text
            location = location.strip()
            lista_endereco.append(location)

            # Size
            size = container.find_all('span', class_='property-card__detail-value js-property-card-value property-card__detail-area js-property-card-detail-area')[0].text
            if '-' not in size:
                size = int(size[:size.find('m')].replace(',','').strip())
            else:
                size = int(size[:size.find('-')].replace(',','').strip())
            lista_tamanho.append(size)

            # Rooms
            quartos = container.find_all('li', class_='property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-room js-property-detail-rooms')[0].text
            quartos = quartos[:quartos.find('Q')].strip()
            if '-' in quartos:
                quartos = quartos[:quartos.find('-')].strip()
            lista_quartos.append(int(quartos))
            
            # Bathrooms
            banheiros = container.find_all('li', class_='property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-bathroom js-property-detail-bathroom')[0].text
            banheiros = banheiros[:banheiros.find('B')].strip()
            if '-' in banheiros:
                banheiros = banheiros[:banheiros.find('-')].strip()
            lista_banheiros.append(int(banheiros))
            
            # Garage
            vagas = container.find_all('li', class_='property-card__detail-item property-card__detail-garage js-property-detail-garages')[0].text
            vagas = vagas[:vagas.find('V')].strip()
            if '--' in vagas:
                vagas = '0'
            lista_vagas.append(int(vagas))

            # Condomínio
            condominio = container.find_all('section', class_='property-card__values')[0].text
            try:
                condominio = int(condominio[condominio.rfind('R$'):].replace('R$','').replace('.','').strip())
            except:
                condominio = 0
            lista_condominio.append(condominio)

            # Amenidades
            try:
                amenidades = container.find_all('ul', class_='property-card__amenities')[0].text
                amenidades = amenidades.split()
            except:
                amenidades = 'Zero'
            lista_amenidades.append(amenidades)

            # url
            link = 'https://www.vivareal.com.br/' + container.find_all('a')[0].get('href')[1:-1]
            lista_sites.append(link)

            # image
            #p = str(container.find_all('img')[0])
            #p

            #2x size thumbnail

            #imgurl = p[p.find('https'):p.rfind('data-src')]
            #imgurl.replace('"', '').strip()
            #lista_fotos.append(imgurl)
    else:
        break
    
    time.sleep(randint(1,2))
    
print('You scraped {} pages containing {} properties.'.format(n_pages, len(lista_preco)))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DO have a choice. There is no need to use Selenium as you can access the data through the api.

There is a restriction on the site that only allows you to paginate through max 10,000 listings. There's far more data that is returned than what you want there, so it's up to you to look through that json response and see if there anything more you want to add:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import math
import time
import random

url = 'https://glue-api.vivareal.com/v2/listings'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36',
           'x-domain': 'www.vivareal.com.br'}
payload = {
'addressCity': 'Salvador',
'addressLocationId': 'BR>Bahia>NULL>Salvador',
'addressNeighborhood': '',
'addressState': 'Bahia',
'addressCountry': 'Brasil',
'addressStreet': '',
'addressZone': '',
'addressPointLat': '-12.977738',
'addressPointLon': '-38.501636',
'business': 'SALE',
'facets': 'amenities',
'unitTypes': 'APARTMENT',
'unitSubTypes': 'UnitSubType_NONE,DUPLEX,LOFT,STUDIO,TRIPLEX',
'unitTypesV3': 'APARTMENT',
'usageTypes': 'RESIDENTIAL',
'listingType': 'USED',
'parentId': 'null',
'categoryPage': 'RESULT',
'size': '350',
'from': '0',
'q': '',
'developmentsSize': '5',
'__vt': '',
'levels': 'CITY,UNIT_TYPE',
'ref': '/venda/bahia/salvador/apartamento_residencial/',
'pointRadius':''}


def get_num_of_listings(priceMin, priceMax, payload, url, previous_priceMax, jsonData, previous_jsonData):
    randInt = random.uniform(5.1, 7.9)
    payload.update({'from':'0'})
    #time.sleep(randInt)
    if priceMax > 2500000:
        priceMax = 100000000
    payload.update({'priceMin':'%s' %priceMin,'priceMax':'%s' %priceMax})
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    listings_count = jsonData['search']['totalCount']
    
    if listings_count < 10000:
        if priceMax < 100000000:
            print ('Price range %s - %s returns %s listings.' %(priceMin, priceMax, listings_count))
            previous_jsonData = jsonData
            previous_priceMax = priceMax
            priceMax += 25000
            listings_count, priceMin, priceMax, previous_priceMax, jsonData, previous_jsonData = get_num_of_listings(priceMin, priceMax, payload, url, previous_priceMax, jsonData, previous_jsonData)
        else:
            previous_jsonData = jsonData
            previous_priceMax = 100000000
        
    priceMin = previous_priceMax + 1
    priceMax = priceMin + 250000 - 1
    return listings_count, priceMin, priceMax, previous_priceMax, jsonData, previous_jsonData
    

rows = []
priceMin = 1
priceMax = 250000
finished = False
aquired = []
while finished == False:
    randInt = random.uniform(5.1, 7.9)
    listings_count, priceMin, priceMax, previous_priceMax, jsonData, previous_jsonData = get_num_of_listings(priceMin, priceMax, payload, url, None, None, None)
    total_pages = math.ceil(previous_jsonData['search']['totalCount'] / 350)
        
    for page in range(1, total_pages+1):
        if page == 1:
            idx=0
            jsonData = previous_jsonData
        else:
            idx = 350*page
            payload.update({'from':'%s' %idx})
            if idx == 9800:
                payload.update({'size':200})
            else:
                payload.update({'size':350})
             
            if idx > 9800:
                continue
            #time.sleep(randInt)
            jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
        
        listings = jsonData['search']['result']['listings']
        for listing in listings:
            listingId = listing['listing']['id']
            if listingId in aquired:
                continue
            zone = listing['listing']['address']['zone']
            size = listing['listing']['usableAreas'][0]
            bedrooms = listing['listing']['bedrooms'][0]
            bathrooms = listing['listing']['bathrooms'][0]
            if listing['listing']['parkingSpaces'] != []:
                parking = listing['listing']['parkingSpaces'][0]
            else:
                parking = None
            price = listing['listing']['pricingInfos'][0]['price']
            try:
                condoFee =  listing['listing']['pricingInfos'][0]['monthlyCondoFee']
            except:
                condoFee =  None
            amenities = listing['listing']['amenities']
            listingUrl = 'https://www.vivareal.com.br' + listing['link']['href']
                
            row = {
            'Id':listingId,
            'Zone' : zone,
            'Size' : size,
            'Bedrooms' : bedrooms,
            'Bathrooms': bathrooms,
            'Garage' : parking,
            'Price': price,
            'Condominio' : condoFee,
            'Amenidades' : amenities,
            'url' : listingUrl}
            
            aquired.append(listingId)

            rows.append(row)
        print('Page %s of %s' %(page, total_pages))
    if priceMax > 100000000:
        print('Done')
        finished = True
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
IPdb [3]: print(df)
               Id  ...                                                url
0      2511396476  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
1      2494354474  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
2      2504461896  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
3      2508574459  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
4      2511489082  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
          ...  ...                                                ...
26244    94618731  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
26245    93437597  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
26246    79341843  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
26247  2455978575  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...
26248  2509913182  ...  https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento...

[26249 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, man! This really works and solved my problem, although I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding it. Where did you get that API from? (https://glue-api.vivareal.com/v2/listings) Thanks again! Great job, much appreciated!

Comment: if you go to Dev Tools (ctrl+shift+I, or right click and select "Inspect") the Dev Tools panel should open up. If you look in the Network -> XHR tabs, you'll see where requests are made (you may need to refresh the browser to see it pop in there). Just fishing around there you'll see that the data is returned in a json format.

Comment: How do i adapt this code to scrap the rest of the information that couldn't be requested due to the website limitation? I'm sorry if this question is kinda stupid, I'm sort of new to python. I tried changing thie for loop here: for page in range(1, total_pages+1), but couldn't come up with a solution.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. you'll have to play around and see what parameters/filters can get you a smaller subset, and then possibly iterate through that. there are some parameters I didn't add in that payload. I'm done for today, but I can peek at it tomorrow and let you know if I find a easy way to do it

Comment: Thanks a lot @chitown88 ! I still haven't figured out how to extract all the data over the 10k limit, but I'm working on it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @abbehusen I'll take a look at it now and get back to you

Comment: Just can't thank you enough. You're amazing.

Comment: ok. looks like using min and max price can be used to create subsets. Let me work o it a bit, as it appears that it blocks when requests are made too fast, so will need a way to work out a delay when needed. otherwise, seems like it will work

Comment: bit clunky, but give it try now

Comment: Thanks again, @chitown88 ! I ran the code and the following error came up: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). ---> 26. The strange thing is that it was doing fine, and suddenly the error appeared. And now, not even the previous code is working (the one that doesn't extract all the data over 10k limit). Could it be that the API is blocking me or something? Just can't thank you enough, man! You are amazing!

Comment: It worked!! The previous problem was really related to API requests restrictions. I'm speechless. Thank you so much!!! Best regards, my friend!

Comment: Ah ya. I ran into that problem too. I have in there short sleep/delay but commented it out as it worked originally without it. But ya, may need to add a slight delay between requests. Slows it down, but should work then. Seems like you go it to go through though. So cool!

Comment: Yes, man! Thanks a lot! Wish you all the best!

Comment: After one year, i just found this amazing answer! Thanks a lot, chitown88! I just have an small question: the total pages variable is divided by 350. Is it because the each page from API has arount 350 real states? Because in the website, it is around 36.

Comment: Yes. If you look at the size parameter in the request, you’ll see it’s set to 350. That means 350 results are returned (not sure why I picked that...might have been the max number allowed). The objective is to get as much data in as few requests to the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe there is NO choice for you to do this. The reason is that with new frontend technologies the html is rendered asynchronous and it requires "real" environment for javascript to be able to run and load the page. For example, with Ajax, you will need a real browser (Chrome, Firefox) to make it work. So, my suggestion is you should keep digging deeper into Selenium and mimic the click event to click each page (clicking on page number like 1..2..3 until the end) then wait until the data loaded, then read the html and extract the data you need.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And does Selenium work in clicking javascript links?

Comment: What about scrapy? Does it work with javascript pages?

Comment: The idea of selenium or any automation framework is to mimic human's action by manipulating a browser. So anything you can do manually can also be repeated by Selenium or others (pupeteer, cucumber ect). You should wait until the links are fully render then click, then get html , then click again, get again and so on.

Comment: @abbehusen If you find my idea useful, please mark it as answer, thank you!